# Highlight words when typed from a list with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to highlight words in a textbox (or some other way to tag or make the word noticeable) if they are on a list (likely an array list with Javascript).

I don't expect this to be real time, a button that checks the words in the textbox will work perfectly fine. Basically an "If Word is (Word1, Word2, etc.) then *Insert change here* to Word."

I am also fine with it just making the word all caps to signify change. Whatever is easy. I'm new to Javascript and only understand the very basic concept on how to do this and would like to learn how to make it interact with a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it bold `<b>Word</b>` or emphasize according to some style with `<em>Word</em>` See this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em for more info on the em tag.

Comment: Yeah, whatever identifies the word has changes is fine with me. I mostly just need to understand how to make it identify and make said change to the word. Bold, Italics, turn it to caps, etc.

Comment: Oh, I see, you cannot style words independently inside a textbox because you cannot have markup inside a textbox value. You could use an editable div instead by setting the ``contenteditable`` property

Comment: I'm requesting assistance in making an array with javascript of a long list of words (100-500) that when typed in a textbox get flagged by the script and altered. Letting me know said word is on the list. 

ie:

var array-name = [word1, word2, ...]; 

I need set it so that if say, I type word1 in a textbox, the script flags the word somehow. Making it bold, caps, w/e. the method doesn't matter. 

<input type="text" id="wordsgohere"> 

The script needs to check the input ID for said words either every few seconds or when an <input type="button"> is selected. HTML isn't the issue, javascript is

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick javascript example working off the contenteditable property referenced in the comments of gabesoft's answer. You can define a list of words, specify the textbox, and then use a button to do the highlights.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bto7jvem/)

HTML:

```
<p contenteditable="true">This is a test of the word highlight system.</p>
<button onClick="highlightWords()">highlight</button>
```

JS:

```
//define words you want highlighted
var arr = ['test', 'system'];

//locate the element on the page to do the word operations
//this will find the first <p> tag
var textbox = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

var highlightWords = function() {
  //foreach word, perform highlighting actions
  arr.forEach(function(word) {

    //build regular expression to match against each variable (word) in our list
    var regex = new RegExp("(" + word + ")", "gi");
    //g = can find multiple instances (global)
    //i = case insenstive

    //replace predefined textbox HTML with 'highlighted' version
    //the regex will find matching words and wrap them in <strong> tags
    //the $1 represents the matched word
    textbox.innerHTML = textbox.innerHTML.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
  });
}
```

Comment: Okay, I get it. I wasn't familiar with regex or gi. I had the concept of var arr and getting it to locate the textbox. But everything else was blank for me. 

I'm still learning javascript. Thank you. =3

Comment: Sure thing, if you think it'll work for you (or at least get you started how you wanted) feel free to accept as answer ;)